# How could I delete DCIM sub folders in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, finder, windows, storage

I am using my windows laptop to move my photos from my iphone. After I moved all of the folders named  `100APPLE` to `104APPLE`, I want to delete those folders in my iphone storage under `DCIM` folder. But when I tend to delete it there is a error. I did not disconnect my iphone or interrupted it. It just shows every time i want to delete the folders.

Here is the screenshot from my laptop
[image]

Is there any way to delete those folders? I already copied it in my laptop. I just want to free some space from my iphone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply **can't** delete them.

Your only option is to delete the subfolders/the images themselves. They need to be there, iOS does not allow you to delete them, therefore Windows shows an error message.

Why would you want to delete the folders anyway? If they contain the images, go ahead and delete those, but deleting a simple folder gives you basically no further storage at all.

This has been discussed on the [Apple Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5541966) as well.

Comment: okay. I thought I can delete those folder like in an android phone. So basically the folder is like a permanent storage for photos right? What I did was copy the folders and save them to my laptop. Now I can safely delete the pictures inside those folders right?

Comment: If you are sure you have all the photos you can go ahead and delete the photos, either with the iPhone itself or from Windows. I would keep a backup of them (and maybe your whole Computer/most important files) though, since hard drives and even SSDs can fail. Yes, those folders are permanent.